# unable to remote/ssh into my virtualbox guest linux OS

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I am stuck and can't figure out why I'm unable to remote into my guest vm.
This is what I'm trying to do:

1. My Worklaptop is running Virtual Box: (Host-Windows, Guest-Fedora 12)
2. When at home (personal network) - Fireup laptop, VirtualBox:Guest-Fedora 12
3. SSH into Guest-Fedora 12 from my personal Mac OSX machine

My VB settings for my guest:

```
Adapter1 - NAT - allow all, cable connected
Adapter2 - Host-only Adapter - allow all, cable connected
open-ssh client on Fedora is installed as I can ssh into other servers.
```

Goal is to basically work from my MacOSX personal machine and SSH into Guest-Fedora 12 vb.

I am unable to do so. When I used "Terminal" from my MacOSX, i'll get an operation timed out message.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install openssh server on fedora? I'm not sure it is by default:

```
# yum install openssh-server
```

And then make sure the service is started?

```
systemctl start sshd
```

Also, NAT networking is not what you want.  See here: http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-virtualbox-networking-part-two.html. That creates an ip address that is only visible to the host.

VirtualBox has a bridged mode that will give you something that looks like another box on your local network.  Try that.

Comment: Ok, I'm actually gotten farther now. It said it was already installed, but downloaded the latest package. I also started sshd. Now, I'm able to use putty from my host and can login, but I'm still unable to do this from my other machine - mac.  Its still showing as operation timed out. Both my laptop and my mac are on the same home wireless network.

Comment: No luck with bridged mode either on first adapter. I have first adapter as bridged mode and 2nd as host-only. I can only login from my host.

Comment: You can ping the bridged mode guest ip address from the windows box, but not from the mac?

Comment: Yes, I am able to ssh from windows box (host), but I'm unable to ssh or ping from the mac. This after its setting to Bridge mode, host only settings for adapter1, adapter2.